# how to make an axios get server side call then send to client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, client

I am getting cors issues when I make this request on the client side:

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log('app loading...');
    axios.get('some/random/api').then((res) => {
      console.log(res, 'res');
    })
  }
```

this is part of my server side code:

```
app.use('/', express.static('public'));

axios.get(url, {
        "headers": {"Authorization": "Bearer "}
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
       //I WANT TO SEND THE RESPONSE HERE TO THE REACT CLIENT
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

how can I then pick this data up on the client side?

thanks

Comment: can you clarify what you are trying to do here? Is `some/random/api` your api service? In your server code, are you making a request to another service (what it looks like) or trying to respond to `some/random/api` request?

Comment: @nikrb yeh sure, im trying to make a call to an api service that is not my own and request the data. on the client im getting cors issues so need to do it server side then send it to the client

Comment: in that case you need to wrap your server code request in a route as suggested by artem's answer. Then when other server responds, you can forward the data to your client using res.json(...) like artem's answer

Answer (score 1):

- Install cors library: 
  `npm install --save cors`
- Import it to your express project: `const cors = require('cors');`
- Attach `cors` to your express app, before routes definitions: `app.use(cors())`

  ```
  const express = require('express')
  const cors = require('cors')
  const app = express()

  app.use(cors())

  app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a Single Route'})
  });
  ```

Comment: ok but then at what point to I send to the client and at what point have you hit the api??

Comment: If i truly understand you: For example define route GET `/test-route` , in this route you process the request, and then response data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix, you can also install this chrome extension

> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

However, the long-lasting solution is using the `yarn add cors` and adding it to your root file in express js.  as highlighted above by @Artem Mirchenko

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your server code in a route, as per artem's answer likey so:

```
app.get('/some/random/api', function (req, res, next) {
  // axios request to other server goes here
  axios.get(...)
    .then( other_server_response => {
      // process other server response if necessary here
      res.json({ returned_data: other_server_response });
    });
});
```

edit: now I look at it, I'm not sure this is what you want. Might just need to call the other service from your client and include cors info.